# C# how to speed up a big project publish

Tags: c#, performance, compilation, publish

How do i publish a project delta so I will not have to wait for all the files that didn't changed ?
for example I have project with big content files that does not change every time I compile but every time i publish to external FTP It takes a long time to publish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could remove the content files from the project itself and maintain them separately.  Keep them in a configured location available to development and production systems and just have the code point to that location.

Comment: Keep the content/data files outside of your code base. This is the cleanest way. Publish the data files separately, if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what I had to do is put the static files on a CDN and replace all local links with the path to the CDN. That way, the publish process only publishes the code files.

Might not be the best solution out there but it makes sense to me to put static files that are rarely modified on a CDN to optimize performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Basem,

Comment: what i really need is a way to compile just the delta and overwrite the existing content , the problem is when i try to run it i get as error about a different file signature , i cant just copy new files to an existing project

Comment: What do you use to publish content? By the way FTP publishing is so slow regardless. I use TeamCity to do all that for me. Once I commit my code to the source control, it triggers the build on the server and publish everything for me

Comment: I use the build in publish of VS-2015